# Discord JDA add custom Emotes on GuildJoin

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I have a .png image which I want to use as a emote. Is there a way to add this image to the server as an emote? I think this should be done in the GuildJoinEvent.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to add a custom emote as soon as your bot joins a server. To achieve that, you could do something like the following in the GuildJoinEvent:

```
Icon icon = Icon.from(new File("image.png"));
event.getGuild().createEmote("MyEmoteName", icon).queue();
```

Comment: I tried it but this error is displaying on console: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided file does not exist! The file exists in the resource folder of IntelliJ and on the root of the main class. Do you know whats the problem?

Comment: You probably didn't use the class loader, right? Try `new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/image.png").toURI())` to instatiate your file object.

Comment: You can also just do `Icon.from(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image.png"))`